# MenuBar cannot be clicked

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmainwindow, qmenubar

I'm trying to learn PyQt5 and currently and making a MenuBar with an `Exit` function and an `Open` function. I currently have the MenuBar showing with shortcuts that work, but I cannot click on the MenuBar when I hover over it. Here is my current code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication, QPushButton, QDesktopWidget, QLabel, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

CURRENT_VERSION = 0.1

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('test')

        window_width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
        window_height = GetSystemMetrics(1)

        self.resize(0.6 * window_width, 0.6 * window_height)
        self.center()

        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Icon.png'))

        #Exit on menubar
        exitAct = QAction('&Exit', self)
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.setStatusTip('Exit applicatiion')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        #Open on menubar
        openAct = QAction('&Open', self)
        openAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAct.setStatusTip('Open Directory')
        openAct.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAct)
        fileMenu.addAction(openAct)

        btn = QPushButton("Test", self)
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(50, 50)

        btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonpress)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.image = QLabel(self)
        self.openDirectoryDialog = ""

        self.show()

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def openFile(self):
        self.openDirectoryDialog=ddir = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Get Dir Path")

    def buttonpress(self):
        label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.move(100,150)
        self.label.setFixedWidth(500)
        self.label.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.label.setText(self.openDirectoryDialog)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Example()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It was working before I added the ability to open a file and only had the `exit` menu item, but I cannot get even that working again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused because the QLabels are above the menu, blocking the click event of this. QMainWindow has a particular structure as shown in the following image:

[image]

If you want to add a widget, you must do it to the Central Widget, when you pass a parent to a widget, it is placed in position `(0, 0) in relation to it.

Making the modifications you get the following:

```
class Example(QMainWindow):
    [...]
    def initUI(self):
        [...]

        #Exit on menubar
        exitAct = QAction('&Exit', self)
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.setStatusTip('Exit applicatiion')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        #Open on menubar
        openAct = QAction('&Open', self)
        openAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAct.setStatusTip('Open Directory')
        openAct.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

        menubar = self.menuBar()

        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAct)
        fileMenu.addAction(openAct)

        centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        btn = QPushButton("Test", centralwidget)
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(50, 50)

        btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonpress)

        self.label = QLabel(centralwidget)
        self.image = QLabel(centralwidget)
        [...]
```

Comment: What a strange error. I accidentally named my widget the same as a field which was causing this exact error. Thanks to you explaining the 0,0 coordinate I was able to find the typo and now my menu responds since there's not an invisible label on it!